# Woocommerce - Selecting "Single-Product-Variations" Plugin Selectors with REST API

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I have a woocommerce store which uses a custom uploader to pull products from ChannelGrabber and push them to Woocommerce with a large degree more detail than what is initially available from CG. Part of the clients request was to have each colour appear as a seperate varation and as such i installed a plugin called ["Show Single Variations".](https://iconicwp.com/products/woocommerce-show-single-variations/)

From the rest API, i was able to correctly create the variants and use the meta key **_jck_wssv_display_title** with the title i wanted. That was perfect. Unfortunately, using the same logic if i try to use **_jck_wssv_variable_show_search** as a meta key i am unable to have the checkbox appear ticked. I've tried setting the value to 1, true, yes... everything i could think of.

I'm 99% sure this is the correct use for it.

```
[
'key' => '_jck_wssv_variable_show_search',
'value' => true
],
[
'key' => '_jck_wssv_display_title',
'value' => $varMetaTitle
]
```

Has anyone had any luck with the REST API and plugins before? Am i just being silly and using the wrong key?

Even after i create the variant, i tried to update it using a **put** statement but the variant itself just ended up being an Orphan.

Any help is appreciated.
**Edit:** I spoke to the author of the plugin for a time and it seems updating anything but the title isn't as simple as a meta. There's more to it than this. I'm struggling to get my head around as to where though. He mentioned calling a "setter" method.. though i'm unsure where to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this took a little bit of brain power to get through. Firstly, you're going to want to make a php file somewhere in the wordpress directory.

The basic premise is to CURL this file with the information you need.

The file i created was roughly like this:

```
<?php

if(!empty($_POST['id']) && !empty($_POST['check'])){

    $varID = $_POST['id']
    //take the id that will be sent in the curl request.

    require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php');
    //tell wordpress we need it to load, so we can reach the plugins.

    Iconic_WSSV_Product_Variation::set_visibility($varID, array("search", "catalog", "filtered"));
    //this calls the function set_visibility from the plugin.
    //it turns on the checkboxes i require for my variations
}
?>
```

Once the file was set up, i went to my script and during the loop for the variants i added:

```
$ch = curl_init();
//initialise curl

$stringToCurl = "id=" . $getVar['id'] . "&check=yes";
//create string including id for this variant.
//i have an extra conditional for security here

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $stringToCurl);
//set the curl options up

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.example.co.uk/my_file.php");
//set the url to the path of the file

curl_exec($ch);
//execute the curl
```

While it's not the most elegant solution, i think it served my purposes well. 
I hope it helps someone else later down the line.